# ERROR:Missing type specifier

Tags: c++, string

I am writing a car class program for my C++ class, and the only part Visual studios wont work with is anything to do with "string and make". I commented them out and the program runs just fine. Our teacher asked us to split it up to 3 separate pages. The error, as posted in the title is MISSING TYPE SPECIFIER. Turns out all that was needed was "using namespace std;" in the car.h file.

Thank you for your help.

```
    #include "stdafx.h"
    #include <iostream>
    #include <string>
    #include <iomanip>
    #include "Car.h"
    using namespace std;


    int main()
    {
        // Declare car object
        Car myCar;
        int speed = 0, year;
        string make;


        cout << "This program will help you with your Car!" << endl;   //         intro message

        cout << "Please enter the Year" << endl;   // store year
        cin >> year;

        cout << "Please enter the Make of the car" << endl;   // store make
        cin >> make;


        // call member functions to set car year and make.
        myCar.setYear(2013);
        myCar.setMake("Mustang GT");

        // call member functions to get car year and make
        cout << "Your car's current year is: " <<  myCar.getYear() << endl;
        cout << "Your car's current make is: " << myCar.getMake;
        cout << "Your car's current speed is : " << speed << " mph" << endl;





        return 0;
     }
```

Here is Car.h

```
#pragma once
#ifndef CAR_H
#define CAR_H



// Car class declaration
class Car
{
    private:
        string make;
        int year;
        int speed;

    public:
        int myCar(int year, string make, int speed);

        int setYear(int carYear);

        int setSpeed(int carSpeed);

        string setMake(string carMake);

        int getYear();

        int getSpeed();

        string getMake();

        void accelerate();

        void brake();


};
```

And here is Car.cpp

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <iomanip>
#include "Car.h"
using namespace std;


//***
//myCar
//**
int Car::myCar(int year, string make, int speed)
{
    int setYear(int year);
    string setMake(string make);
    return year, make, speed;
}


//**********
// setYear
//*********
int Car::setYear(int carYear)
{
    year = carYear;
    return carYear;

}


//************
// setMake
//************
string Car::setMake(string carMake)
{

    make = carMake;


}
//***    

//***
//setSpeed
//***
int Car::setSpeed(int carSpeed)
{
    speed = carSpeed;
    return carSpeed;


}
//***

//***
//getYear
//***
int Car::getYear()
{

    return year;

}
//***

//***
//getMake
//***
string Car::getMake()
{
    return make;

}


//***
//getSpeed
//***
int Car::getSpeed()
{

    return speed;

}
//***

//***
// Accelerate
//***
void Car::accelerate()
{
    int speed = 0;
    speed += 5;


}
//***

//***
// Brake
//***
void Car::brake()
{
    int speed = 0;
    speed -= 5;

}
//***
```

Comment: Something important is missing from your question. That would be an actual question. "My homework doesn't compile", without even showing the compilation error, is not a question.

Comment: Nothing specifically wrong with asking questions about homework, but yes, ask a question.  Show what you've tried thus far, and expand upon what is/isn't working for you.  In general, "my code doesn't work" isn't a very good way to get a response.  More specifically, what errors happen when you try and compile, and what steps have you gone through to try and fix them?

Comment: You defined setMake to return a string, but you don't use a return value and you don't return anything.

Comment: I thought "Missing type specifier"
was clear enough. 

I dont get this website. You go too into detail with your problem, you get downvoted by trolls. You give the code and straight to the point with the title and the question, you get downvoted by trolls.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `setMake` function it's declared as a string but returns no value. I believe you forgot to return the passed value.

```
//************
// setMake
//************
string Car::setMake(string carMake)
{

    make = carMake;
    return make; // This line should do the trick

}
```

I do suggest next time taking a closer look at what the compiler outputs, since it likely gave you a line number and even the name of the function where the issue was.

**Side note**: Generally set functions are declared as void since they usually don't need to return anything.

Comment: Thank you this was very helpful. Turns out, my teacher didnt know for whatever reason visual studios, decided the uising namespace std; was missing from the car.h file. My Teacher said since it is linked to the main drive, it shouldnt need it. But thats what was causing the Type specifier error.